# Spotipy OAuth2 Access Token without pasting URL to console

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, pyside2, spotipy

I am currently working on a Python Spotify Managing Application.
I am using PySide2 (Qt) to create the GUI. Qt has a Browser feature to visit websites. I am using this code to authenticate:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

auth = SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope, cache_path='user_cache',
                    client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret,
                    redirect_uri=redirect_uri)

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth)

print(auth.get_auth_response())
```

When I run this code it opens a browser window in Chrome and asks me to login to my Spotify account. Then it redirects me to my redirect_uri. I have to paste this link into the console.

[image: Console Output]

My problem is that I don't want to paste the URI into the console. I want the App to get the url from inside the PySide2 (Qt) browser (I know how to get the current link and so on) and paste it to the console automatically.

My questions are:

1. Does Spotipy have a feature to make an OAuth2 without pasting the link to the console? I want to bypass the input and pass the redirect link directly to spotipy.
2. Is it possible to select the browser it opens manually?

I'd like to do it without Flask, just PySide2 (PyQt, Qt, etc.) Best case: Just get the token from the query and use it for api requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to implement a new scheme in Qt WebEngine where the request is redirected.

On the other hand Spotipy uses Requests making the requests block the eventloop causing the GUI to freeze so I have modified the requests making them asynchronous.

```
from functools import cached_property, partial
import threading
import types

import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth, SpotifyClientCredentials

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineCore, QtWebEngineWidgets


class ReplySpotify(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, func, args=(), kwargs=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._results = None
        self._is_finished = False
        self._error_str = ""
        threading.Thread(
            target=self._execute, args=(func, args, kwargs), daemon=True
        ).start()

    @property
    def results(self):
        return self._results

    @property
    def error_str(self):
        return self._error_str

    def is_finished(self):
        return self._is_finished

    def has_error(self):
        return bool(self._error_str)

    def _execute(self, func, args, kwargs):
        if kwargs is None:
            kwargs = {}
        try:
            self._results = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            self._error_str = str(e)
        self._is_finished = True
        self.finished.emit()


def convert_to_reply(func, *args, **kwargs):
    reply = ReplySpotify(func, args, kwargs)
    return reply


class ConvertToReply(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
        klass = super().__call__(*args, **kw)
        for key in dir(klass):
            value = getattr(klass, key)
            if isinstance(value, types.MethodType) and not key.startswith("_"):
                wrapped = partial(convert_to_reply, value)
                setattr(klass, key, wrapped)
        return klass


class QSpotify(spotipy.Spotify, metaclass=ConvertToReply):
    pass


class QOauthHandler(QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler):
    authenticated = QtCore.Signal(str, dict)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._html = ""

    @property
    def html(self):
        return self._html

    @html.setter
    def html(self, html):
        self._html = html

    def requestStarted(self, request):
        request_url = request.requestUrl()
        if request_url.host() == "oauth":
            query = QtCore.QUrlQuery(request_url.query())
            d = dict()
            for k, v in query.queryItems():
                d[k] = v
            self.authenticated.emit(request_url.path(), d)

            buf = QtCore.QBuffer(parent=self)
            request.destroyed.connect(buf.deleteLater)
            buf.open(QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
            buf.write(self.html.encode())
            buf.seek(0)
            buf.close()
            request.reply(b"text/html", buf)


class QSpotifyOAuth(QtCore.QObject, SpotifyOAuth):
    authenticationRequired = QtCore.Signal(QtCore.QUrl)
    codeChanged = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(
        self,
        client_id=None,
        client_secret=None,
        redirect_uri=None,
        state=None,
        scope=None,
        cache_path=None,
        username=None,
        proxies=None,
        show_dialog=False,
        requests_session=True,
        requests_timeout=None,
        parent=None,
    ):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent=None)
        SpotifyOAuth.__init__(
            self,
            client_id,
            client_secret,
            redirect_uri,
            state,
            scope,
            cache_path,
            username,
            proxies,
            show_dialog,
            requests_session,
            requests_timeout,
        )
        self._code = ""

    def get_auth_response(self, state=None):
        url = QtCore.QUrl.fromUserInput(self.get_authorize_url())
        self.authenticationRequired.emit(url)
        loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
        self.codeChanged.connect(loop.quit)
        loop.exec_()
        if state is None:
            state = self.state
        return state, self.code

    @property
    def code(self):
        return self._code

    def autenticate(self, values):
        self._code = values.get("code", "")
        self.codeChanged.emit()


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.view, stretch=1)
        lay.addWidget(self.log, stretch=1)

        self.view.hide()

        client_id = ""
        client_secret = ""
        self.qauth = QSpotifyOAuth(
            cache_path="user_cache",
            client_id=client_id,
            client_secret=client_secret,
            redirect_uri="qt://oauth/spotify",
            scope="user-library-read",
        )
        self.qclient = QSpotify(auth_manager=self.qauth)
        self.qauth.authenticationRequired.connect(self.view.load)
        self.qauth.authenticationRequired.connect(self.view.show)

        reply = self.qclient.current_user_saved_tracks()
        reply.setParent(self)
        reply.finished.connect(partial(self.on_finished, reply))

    @cached_property
    def view(self):
        return QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()

    @cached_property
    def log(self):
        return QtWidgets.QTextEdit(readOnly=True)

    def handle(self, path, values):
        self.qauth.autenticate(values)
        self.view.hide()

    def on_finished(self, reply):
        reply.deleteLater()
        for item in reply.results["items"]:
            track = item["track"]
            text = "<b>%s</b> %s" % (track["artists"][0]["name"], track["name"])
            self.log.append(text)

        if reply.results["items"]:
            new_reply = self.qclient.next(reply.results)
            new_reply.setParent(self)
            new_reply.finished.connect(partial(self.on_finished, new_reply))


def main():
    import sys

    scheme = QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineUrlScheme(b"qt")
    QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineUrlScheme.registerScheme(scheme)

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.setOrganizationName("qtspotify")
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.setApplicationName("Qt Spotify")

    handler = QOauthHandler()

    profile = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineProfile.defaultProfile()
    """profile.setPersistentCookiesPolicy(
        QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineProfile.NoPersistentCookies
    )"""
    profile.installUrlSchemeHandler(b"qt", handler)

    w = Widget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    handler.authenticated.connect(w.handle)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Note:** You must add the url "qt://oauth/spotify" to the project settings in the dashboard:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly!
I just have another question: I can't write an @ to the input field in the browser. I noticed that it doesn't work with any CTRL + ALT + [KEY]  symbols. I have to copy it from outside and then paste it.